# Android live wallpaper in Opengl ES 2.0 and preference management

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, live-wallpaper, android-wallpaper

I'm writing a Opengl ES 2.0 live wallpaper for Android starting from article found [here](http://www.learnopengles.com/how-to-use-opengl-es-2-in-an-android-live-wallpaper/).
In the code of the article to apply preference changes, you need to restart wallpaper (as wrote in section 4. Viewing the new live wallpaper).

I want to bypass this limitation: i want to switch from preference activity to wallpaper and recreate scene acknowledging changes in preferences.

[image]

I try to put code for scene generation (texture bindind, shader rebuild, etc) in `onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height)` of the renderer, but this solution causes many crash (due to synchronization, i suppose).

Has anybody got the same problem?